# Deleting without copying to clipboard in Windows?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Here is a typical workflow I would like to follow:

1. copy some data from Excel spreadsheet into the clipboard
2. in vim , delete the data in the file using `ggdG`
3. then paste the data into the file from the clipboard (I use `CTRL-V` as I am under Windows)

This does not work because step 2 copies the deleted data into the clipboard.

Is it possible to delete without affecting the clipboard ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When deleting the buffer contents in Vim, you can send it to the *black hole* register `"_`. From [`:help quote_`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote_):

> When writing to this register, nothing happens.  This can be used to delete
>   text without affecting the normal registers.

So simply use this command in your step 2:

```
gg"_dG
```

Or you can also use the [`:delete`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Adelete) command with a range:

```
:%d _
```

This Ex command deletes every line into the black hole register.

Comment: Simpler is of course `:%d _`

Comment: Tnhanks @D.BenKnoble! Great call! Incorporated it into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, everything is possible in Vim!

There is a register system in vim, and the clipboard is the register `+` (or `*`, it depends)

By default, the text you cut is put in the clipboard register, but you can put it in a black hole register (`:h quote_`) like so:

```
gg"_dG
```

The `"_` here tells vim to put what you're about to cut in a black hole register, so your `+` register (a.k.a. your clipboard) stays untouched.

And the magic doesn't stop there, if it's a task you do often, you can set up a **mapping** to do that, for example:

```
nnoremap gd gg"_dG
```

So that next time you need to delete a whole file, you just need to hit `gd`

I personally have a mapping on my `\` key like so:

```
nnoremap \ "_
```

So when I need to keep my clipboard, I begin my keystrokes with `\`

Comment: In fact, the deleted text should not be put in the clipboard, not without tweaking some options!

Comment: Ahaha okay then you might want to disable the xterm_clipboard option. When you type `vim --version`, you should see the option with a `+` before it right now, which you don't want.. but I'm not sure how to do that on windows

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to do that with buffers?

Comment: I'm not OP :) Just responding... I meant that by default, `ggdG` should delete into the unnamed register and `"1`. However, if `clipboard` contains `unnamed` or `unnamedplus`, than the delete will also get sent to the clipboard. This decidedly *not* the default!

Comment: You're mixing up buffers with registers. `"+`, `"*` and `"a` are all **registers**. Furthermore your command doesn't fix the issue, since you're using `"a` as the register for `gg` and not for `dG` which is the part that writes to registers. Also, there's no reason to use `"a` or a letter register which would be overwritten too... you can simply use `"_`, the *black hole* register (see `:help quote_`).

Comment: I corrected my answer, thank you for your comments!

Comment: @Zorzi Thanks that's much better now!

Answer (score 2):

You could visual select with `v` or select the whole line with `V` and then press `p` or `P` to replace the selected text with the one in clipboard (I think it will work with yours Ctrl+v as well).